# Optimizing a large MySQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization

Today I was told by my hosting provider that my database must be blocked immediately. I have a query that causes huge load on the server. Do you know how can I optimize my query just to make the server less loaded?

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,
       `why_me`, 
       `created`,
       `thumbnail`,
       `rating_date`,
       CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS name,
       SUBSTRING(why_me, 1, 27) as subwhy,
       COUNT(`rating_date`) AS total,
       MAX(`rating_date`) AS maxrate
  FROM (`user_profiles`)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `rates` ON `user_profiles`.`id`=`rates`.`user_id`
  JOIN `users` ON `user_profiles`.`user_id`=`users`.`id`
  WHERE `users`.`activated` =  '1'
      AND `last_name` != ""
      AND `first_name` != ""
      AND  concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name) COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI  LIKE '%%'
  GROUP BY `user_profiles`.`user_id`
  ORDER BY `total` desc
```

I'd appreciate any help from you. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables? Try putting EXPLAIN in front of the query and post the results.

Comment: Can you check other questions related to optimizing MySQL queries to see what people need to see to help you? There's insufficient information provided here.

Comment: One solution will definitely be using the "concat" and "substring" only for the result-set and not for every row matching.
this can be done by removing the concat and substring and add them to wrapping select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND  concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name) COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI  LIKE '%%'
```

has no effect but is expensive (long running). It scans all the rows one-by-one without returning anything usefull. Remove!

Log in into phpmyadmin and run this query with "**EXPLAIN**" prepended, i.e. "EXPLAIN SELECT users...".
Post the result. It will show us if SQL can directly adress the required rows, or if it searching them one-by-one. Look out for the row used keys: if it´s empty, you need additioanl indeces:

1) Make sure you have an **index** on every column used for the joins, i.e. rates.user_idand user_profiles.user_id.

2) Make sure you have indeces on everything used for the where part with a high **cardinality**, i.e. first_name and last_name.

3) Even better: Create an **index over 3 columns**: activated,first_name,last_name

4) The GROUP and ORDER BY are causing the buildt of a temporary table. Can you port some of this **logic into PHP**?

5) **Cache** the result. That´s nothing to be done in real time!